# How to make a .jar out from an Android Studio project

Tags: java, android, jar, android-studio

I'm using AndroidStudio and I have this project as shown:

[image]

What is inside the blue circle is myLib. myLib also needs to use an external lib that is inside the red circle, and an apache package (green circle).

So I want to make this whole thing become a single .jar, so I can use it in another projects.

A step-by-step guide would be really appreciated, I'm a beginner in the developer world.

Thanks!

Comment: I think what you want is a aar file (Android archive) that one can be linked quiet simple as dependency. Basically you need to create a Android library project. But I cannot write the exact steps from mind.

Comment: I need a .jar file so I can use in any java project. Not only android's.

Comment: Must be almost the same - make a library project and the export it.

Comment: [This bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58287) describes a deficiency in the Android gradle plugin that prevents easily hacking the gradle buildfile to add a jar target...

Answer (score 150):

- Open build.gradle for library project
  [image]
- Write two tasks in build.gradle -- deleteJar and createJar and add rule createJar.dependsOn(deleteJar, build)
  [image]

The code from above:

```
task deleteJar(type: Delete) {
    delete 'libs/jars/logmanagementlib.jar'
}           

task createJar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
    into('libs/jars/')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename('classes.jar', 'logmanagementlib.jar')
}

createJar.dependsOn(deleteJar, build)
```

- Expand gradle panel from right and open all tasks under yourlibrary->others. You will see two new tasks there -- createJar and deleteJar
  [image]
- Double click on createJar
  [image]
- Once the task run successfully, get your generated jar from path mentioned in createJar task i.e. libs/xxxx.jar
  [image]
- copy the newly generated jar into your required project's lib folder-->right click-->select "add as library"

Comment: @AbhinavTyagi Have a library in my Android project, but whenever I change the source of the library, the changes are not affected to .jar file, its still maintaining old code in .jar. I have tried build, createjar etc. Any ideas?

Comment: Whenever I made any changes, I had to run the tasks again as shown above. Try cleaning the build and rerun the scripts when you have made changes.

Comment: You know this would be much better if it didn't involve screenshots.

Comment: Sometimes people understands by viewing rather than reading. It's a good UX you see ☺

Comment: I fixed it for you :)

Comment: Thanks... But I wanted people to type to have some finger exercise :D

Comment: Well, then I should tell you that I'm not sure about `release`. I've got `debug` and `default`, but no `release` folder. What version of the plugin are you using? Do you know if this is documented anywhere?

Comment: I don't have `release` folder.

Comment: try and replace the release folder with what you want. see if it works for you.

Comment: Use `default` if you don't have `release`. Changing to that fixed my issue.

Comment: @kami +1 to use `default` or `debug`

Comment: I don't have `bundles` folder so no `classes.jar` appearing and have nothing to copy. what can i do to solve this?

Comment: @user2890234 check above comments. Use the folders you have and modify the script.

Comment: @Abhinav Tyagi, thanks for your answer. but above comments solve lack of `release/debug/default` folders while i even have no `bundles`, so no `classes.jar` creating when running `createJar`

Comment: What are you trying to copy?? Are we supposed to target the folders containing the APK file??  I mean in the line from('build/intermediates/bundles/default') what is this directory holding for you. There is no folder in my android studio with the name bundles, and I keep getting NO SOURCE in createJar task

Comment: change from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/') to from('build/intermediates/packaged-classes/release/') for Android Studio 3.1.3 and Gradle version 4.4

Comment: I don't have the 'intermediates' fold in 'build'... Android studio 3.2.1

Comment: you can check build/outputs/apk

Comment: I don't see even this folder build/intermediates/packaged-classes/release/

Comment: I'm using Android Studio 4.1.1 and using folder 'build/intermediates/app_classes/release'

Comment: need not to create a new one ,it aready had a createFulJarRelease/createFullJarDebug，double click and it will build a full.jar which is what need

Answer (score 65):

If you set up the code as a plain Java module in Gradle, then it's really easy to have Gradle give you a jar file with the contents. That jar file will have only your code, not the other Apache libraries it depends on. I'd recommend distributing it this way; it's a little weird to bundle dependencies inside your library, and it's more normal for users of those libraries to have to include those dependencies on their own (because otherwise there are collisions of those projects are already linking copies of the library, perhaps of different versions). What's more, you avoid potential licensing problems around redistributing other people's code if you were to publish your library.

Take the code that also needs to be compiled to a jar, and move it to a separate plain Java module in Android Studio:

1. **File** menu > **New Module...** > **Java Library**
2. Set up the library, Java package name, and class names in the wizard. (If you don't want it to create a class for you, you can just delete it once the module is created)
3. In your Android code, set up a dependency on the new module so it can use the code in your new library:
4. **File** > **Project Structure** > **Modules** > *(your Android Module)* >  **Dependencies** > **+** > **Module dependency**. See the screenshot below:
   [image]
5. Choose your module from the list in the dialog that comes up:
   [image]

Hopefully your project should be building normally now. After you do a build, a jar file for your Java library will be placed in the **build/libs** directory in your module's directory. If you want to build the jar file by hand, you can run its **jar** build file task from the Gradle window:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer was really helpful, most in the last screenshot that shows the Gradle tasks. I didn't know that. I could follow your the steps, but I still missing the org.apache.http.Header.  How can I import it into my lib?

Comment: What do you mean when you say you're missing it?

Comment: I can't import it. Like when you hit Ctrl+Space to see the imports' options, org.apache.http.Header isn't there. But I see others like com.sun.xml...Header.

Comment: If you're running a version of Android Studio earlier than 0.4.3, that's your problem -- please upgrade.

Comment: I'm using 0.4.4. It seems like when you create a new Java Library (File menu > New Module... > Java Library) it comes without the apache's package. I miss it in my lib module, not in my app's.

So how can I import this specific package inside my lib module?

Comment: Oh, you have to make sure it's in your lib module's dependencies, too.

Comment: Yeah, it's not, so how can I fix it? And a last doubt, when I execute a gradle jar task, where can I find the resulting .jar file? 

Anyway, Im really grateful for your help! :)

Comment: Go through the same Project Structure > dependencies flow, but choose your library module instead of your project, and add the dependency in the same way. In my answer I say that it puts the jar file in the build/libs dir in its module directory.

Comment: I got: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams. That's my external library I'm compiling with mine.

Comment: Hi Scott, it doesn't feel right to have to do this to get a jar file for a microsoft sponsored project on github. I'm trying to use SignalR Android client in my android studio project and I must have taken a left turn somewhere. Surely I should not make my jar and put the MS "jar" inside of it. Thanks.

Comment: It work with java library only, and jar task in android library not exist

Comment: When I move my classes into a new module, android studio complains about all the import statements I've used saying (e.g.) 'cannot resolve symbol Intent'.

Comment: I resolved my import issue (cannot resolve symbol) by creating **Android Library** instead of Java Library (**New Module... > Android Library**)

Comment: In the latest version of Android Studio (3.4.1) the gradle script is called 'createFullJarDebug' and 'createFullJarRelease' respectively.

Answer (score 40):

In the Android Studio IDE, access the "*Run Anything bar*" by:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd> +`gradle CreateFullJarRelease`+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

After that you'll find your artefact in this folder in your project
`Build > Intermediates > Full_jar > Release > CreateFullJarRelease > full.jar`

---

## OR

---

Gradle has already a `Task` for that, in the gradle side-menu, under the `other` folder.

[image: gradle toolbar]

Then scroll down to `createFullJarRelease` and click it.

[image: Gradle Tasks]

After that you'll find your artefact in this folder in your project

`Build > Intermediates > Full_jar > Release > CreateFullJarRelease > full.jar`

Comment: Can't see this option. Has this been added on a recent Studio version ?

Comment: I build and when find *.jar it's name is : full.jar. 30mins to found it lol

Comment: In my case, I found it in `build\intermediates\intermediate-jars\release`

Comment: I have a question. In my case, it generates 3 jar files. `classes.jar`, `full.jar`, and `res.jar`. Should I import all jar files whenever I want to use it?

Comment: Just use the full.jar

Comment: Please explain what your first image is.  It looks like a menu.  How do we get there?

Comment: @SteveWhite Yes it's the Gradle menu/toolbar, can be found on the right side in the Android IDE. Or on the keyboard dubble tap CTRL then type "gradle CreateFullJarRelease". =)

Comment: I don't have the `createFullJarRelease` option, only `createMockableJar`. Any reason why this might be?

Comment: My answer was posted 2018, could be that Gradle have changed the name of the Gradle task or removed those tasks. Haven't check that for a while.

Comment: my output was in app/build not build

Answer (score 12):

Simply add this to your java module's build.gradle. It will include dependent libraries in archive.

```
mainClassName = "com.company.application.Main"

jar {
  manifest { 
    attributes "Main-Class": "$mainClassName"
  }  

  from {
    configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
  }
}
```

This will result in [module_name]/build/libs/[module_name].jar file.

Comment: But would a .jar library have a Main class?
The OP says they're building a .jar file "so I can use in another projects" (sic).  That sounds like a library.

Comment: Only this guy actually understood that, just jar creation doesn't solve prob. what if we need to execute it. Above code avoids "Can't execute jar- file: “no main manifest attribute”" error.

Answer (score 2):

I had a supplement;
In the new version Android Studio(for me is: Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7784292, built on October 1, 2021)
In gradle panel, it has no task in default.
Go to the Android Studio ---Settings--Experimental--Gradle tab, uncheck"Do not build Gradle task list during Gradle sync", then click File--Sync project with Gradle files, then the task appeared in the Gradle Panel.

Then follow the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52681317/4065069

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
task deleteJar(type: Delete) {
    delete 'libs/mylibrary.jar'
}           

task exportjar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/intermediates/compile_library_classes/release/')
    into('libs/')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename('classes.jar', 'mylibrary.jar')
}

exportjar.dependsOn(deleteJar, build)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Gradle tab in Android Studio , then select library project .
2. Then go to Tasks
3. Then go to Other
4. Double click on bundleReleaseaar

You can find your `.aar` files under `your_module/build/outputs/aar/your-release.aar`

[image: Here image]

Comment: I don't see any "Gradle Tab" anywhere.  Finally I typed "Gradle" in the Help search, and got something like your Gradle view.  But the list inside is very different, much shorter than yours.  There is no bundleReleaseaar under Tasks->Other.  There is a "createJar", but when I click that, I get "Task 'createJar' not found in root project..."
I'm stuck.

And... why do we want .aar files?  The OP asked for a .jar file.  Is that the same thing>

Comment: But question is how to make `.jar` not `.aar`

Answer (score 1):

In case of this [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35431416/6401241) not working for you

Use this

```
task createJar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/intermediates/packaged-classes/release/')
    into('libs/jars/')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename('classes.jar', 'plugin.jar')
}
```

Instead of this

```
task createJar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
    into('libs/jars/')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename('classes.jar', 'logmanagementlib.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.jar file will be automatically generate when u compile/run your application.

You can find your class.jar file from root_folder/app/build/intermediates/bundles/debug

[image: jar file location]

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

You can  convert `.aar -> .jar`

If you run a gradle task from AndroidStudio[<sup>[More]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61918303/4770877)

```
assembleRelease 
//or
bundleReleaseAar
```

or via terminal

```
./gradlew <moduleName>:assembleRelease
//or
./gradlew <moduleName>:bundleReleaseAar
```

then you will able to find `.aar` in

```
<project_path>/build/outputs/aar/<module_name>.aar
//if you do not see it try to remove this folder and repeat the command
```

`.aar`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65789668/4770877) file is a zip file with aar extension that is why you can replace `.aar` with `.zip` or run

```
unzip "<path_to/module_name>.aar"
```

Answer (score -1):

the way i found was to find the project compiler output (project structure > project).
then find the complied folder of the module you wish to turn to a jar, 
compress it with zip and change the extension of the output from zip to jar.