# How to create a jar library (not aar) in android studio?

Tags: jar, android-studio, aar

how can i create a jar binary library project in android studio that can be used in other projects (meaning - an sdk)?

if it is possible, i want it to contain both java files and native cpp code (java files will start audio listening and cpp files for analysis).

there is no resources/layouts in the library.

if i add an android library module, its ouput is an aar file and not jar.
i read that eclipse does not support aar and so that is why i want it to be jar.

thanks a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a .jar out from an Android Studio project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712714/how-to-make-a-jar-out-from-an-android-studio-project)

Comment: well for now i just use aar... cos it can also contain my native library

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to put aside the Android "nature" of Android Studio and just write and build a normal Java/C++ project with Gradle. Your first stops will be [Java quickstart](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html) and [Native support](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/nativeBinaries.html) documentation of Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

In gradle find command "createFullJarDebug"
This command will generate jar file under  build\intermediates\full_jar\debug\createFullJarDebug\full.jar

then you could use it.