# Delphi 10.1 Berlin - Java2OP: class or interface expected

Tags: java, android, delphi, firemonkey

I'm using `Delphi 10.1 Berlin`. I want to call Java codes from Delphi. So, I created JAR file in `Android Studio` ([this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30864461/5106997) helped to me). Then I opened `Java2OP.exe` from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\bin\converters\java2op` directory. I moved the jar file to this directory. Then I worked this commands in CMD:
`SET PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin"`
`Java2OP.exe -jar ..\libmylib.jar -unit ..\Androidapi.JNI.MyLib`
But I get this error:

```
Warning: error opening ReservedWordsOP.txt
Warning: error opening ReservedWordsC.txt
Parsing xml: C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\bin\converters\java2op\bootclasses.xml
Parsing jar: ..\libmylib.jar
class or Interface expected
```

This my Java class for JAR:

```
public class Test
{
  public String work()
  {
    return "Hello World!";
  }
}
```

Also I tried different Java codes, but result is same. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Those files are missing from the installation. See https://plus.google.com/+RikvanKekem/posts/iGH3mGNYkzP. You can download them [here](https://gist.github.com/jpluimers/e1a0b4c8523eb3adeaa17be745ac03e5).

Comment: I downloaded the text files and I moved `java2op` directory, and when I worked same command, I get same error: `Java2OP.exe -jar ..\libmylib.jar -unit Androidapi.JNI.MyLib`
`Parsing xml: C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\bin\converters\java2op\bootclasses.xml
Parsing jar: ..\libmylib.jar
class or Interface expected`

Comment: Note that `destructor` is misspelled in `ReservedWordsOP.txt`.

Comment: Thanks, I replaced, but result is same.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and solved it removing spaces from path files. 
Probably the Java2OP is calling the Java passing the path without quotes.

Comment: It seems you are correct, copying `Java2OP.exe` to a non-whitespace directory and running it from there fixed the issue for me.