# How to restrict to open sqlite database in Android library project while creating jar file

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, jar, android-library

I am creating Android library project in android studio and have dependent jar file inside library project.

Main idea is that I can distribute that jar file, so that other applications can easily integrate this functionality using the jar file within their apps.

I have used SQLite database in Android library project. But I want to **restrict user to open SQLite database**. So there is any way to restrict the same using Proguard or something else ?

I have followed below link to create .jar file with dependencies

[Android studio make jar file with dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36001814/android-studio-make-jar-file-with-dependencies)

After creating .jar, I am using this jar to testproject to test and I am able to open created SQLite database which I want to restrict.