# How to make a third dependency or jar in Android studio?

Tags: android

As a new android developer, I just know how to import the third dependencies made by other android developers.But now ,I write a simple custom view ,including a class : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEPkL.png) and a declare-styleable:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4DqG.png),for convenience for the future,I want make it to a dependency or a jar.I don't know how to do it.Thanks for your help!

Comment: use this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712714/how-to-make-a-jar-out-from-an-android-studio-project

Answer (score 0):

A .jar is a compiled Java bitcode for the jvm. Google android Java compiles into dex and it packed into a .apk. I would be utterly shocked if you could ever use a jar file. In general android apks files contain everything needed to run the app they don't tend to depend on anything else.

You can setup intents to pass things around throughout the larger environment but in general if you need the code for several projects, just include the source to be recompiled. You might be able to directly include a .dex but it would certainly not be preferred.