# Generate jar in Android Studio 2.1.2

Tags: android, jar

I am planning to make jar file via Android Studio. The current version I am using is 2.1.2 and I have gone through the link [How to make a .jar out from an Android Studio project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712714/how-to-make-a-jar-out-from-an-android-studio-project). This was not helping me. since I tried to generate the jar and found nothing happened.

The thing I did as the link said are

- created a module name testLib (Android Library -> the reason I chose android library is to make use of common shared library file and permissions for android 6.0)
- And then I executed createJar and deleteJar in the gradel list.
- My Module:libtest is as follows

```
task deleteJar(type: Delete){
    delete 'libs/libtest.jar'
}

task createJar(type: Copy){
    from('build/intermediates/bundeles/release')
    into('libs/')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename('classes.jar','libtest.jar')
}

createJar.dependsOn(deleteJar, build)
```

The above resulted with empty libs folder

Please help me with a solution. Thanks in ADVANCE

Comment: https://gist.github.com/daniellevass/2c46cf33e3814e685b47

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put wrong from location:

```
from('build/intermediates/bundles/release')
```

not

```
from('build/intermediates/bundeles/release')
```

Comment: Nice it worked. thank you for helping me. and I added ../app/libs/ to place the same in my app folder