# How can i make whole android project as jar file

Tags: android

Here I want to make a whole android project as jar file which is further used in Unity. My android project is like http://www.truiton.com/2015/05/capture-record-android-screen-using-mediaprojection-apis/ .

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/330809/integration-of-jar-file-using-jni.html

And main things is that how can I make this whole project as jar file.

```
// How can i do that
package jni;     

public class TestClass 
{
 private String a;     
 public TestClass()
 {
     a="Hi all";
 }

 public String func()
 {
     return a;
 }
 }
```

Comment: please check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35431416/6414107) , might help you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a whole android project as jar file, I think what you need is an aar file, which will contain all your build files (the java files and res files),

You can choose the "Android Library" type in File > New Module to create a new Android Library.

If your library is set up as an Android library (i.e. it uses the apply `plugin: 'com.android.library'` statement in its **build.gradle** file), it will output an **.aar** when it's built. It will show up in the **build/outputs/aar/** directory in your module's directory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.can u explain in detail?

Comment: An aar file is a android library file, it can include everything needed to build an app, including source code, resource files, and an Android manifest. However, instead of compiling into an APK that runs on a device, an Android library compiles into an Android Archive (AAR) file that you can use as a dependency for an Android app module. checkout this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html) for more insight cheers