# AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError from running function in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, shared-libraries, android-studio-2.2

Im running trying to run a library that I load from gradle in unity, here is the gradle code to load the library which i put inside my dependecies in gradle

```
compile 'com.voxeet.sdk:core:0.7.798'
```

I can compile normally in android studio, create a jar in android studio using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35431416/2698551)

I also check it is inside ***my project -> open module -> dependencies*** and it exist in this location

So I have this block of code in my java file

```
public static void ConnectVoxeet(){
    UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("AndroidBridge", "AcceptValueFromAndroid", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ");
    VoxeetSdk.sdkInitialize(mainActivity,
            "OTg1azFscWFkNjNhcQ",
            "NW1ybmkxMDdmbmowcTUxcjliMmpjN3NzNnA",
            null
            );

    Log.wtf(TAG,"initialize Voxeet");
}
```

It will run the Log wtf and unity send message to unity

but i throws this error when i sees the voxeetsdk

```
AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lvoxeet/com/sdk/core/VoxeetSdk;
```

i dont have any jar file or aar file just for voxeet and only way i use its class is through the compile 'com.voxeet.sdk:core:0.7.798' in gradle

Is there any settings or anything i need to add for it to call the library or how do i add it in the jar if it is actually missing?

Comment: You said you created a jar, and also mentioned " dont have any jar file or aar file", is this paradoxical?

Comment: find voxeet jar/aar file and add it in your Unity project