# Custom keyboard with popup emoji

Tags: android, emoji, custom-keyboard

I want to add popup emoji like google keyboard. My problem is how to make half screen activity to showing popup screen and how to use it in my class that extended from `InputMethodService` implements `KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener`.

I used [emojicon](https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon) library from github.

If i want to use [this](https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon) github project how to download respective jar file?

Comment: Have you checked this link : https://github.com/tomgersic/AndroidKeyLogger

Comment: @AdityaVyas-Lakhan i edited my question. please help me.thanks a lot

Comment: did you download jar?

Comment: @AdityaVyas-Lakhan link is broken, delete everything after comma.

Comment: @AdityaVyas-Lakhan yes, how to download jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of jar you can add the https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon/tree/master/lib as an Android module to your application and can use it in the same way as shown in sample app https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon/tree/master/example
It allows you to keep track of the library project code. In future, if you ever wanted to do some change in the library project, you can do it easily.

If you want you can generate the jar file on your own from the library project.
Please check:
[How to make a .jar out from an Android Studio project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712714/how-to-make-a-jar-out-from-an-android-studio-project)

Comment: this library is working fine but height and width is no match parent can you please tell me what is problem or any alternative to implement emoji in keyboard