# How to export jar file using android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Sorry for my English. I am new in android. How to export jar file using the android studio. I searched some code. Here the code:

```
task deleteJar(type: Delete) {
   delete 'release/libss.jar'
}

task createJar(type: Copy) {
   from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
   into('release/')
   include('classes.jar')
   rename('classes.jar', 'libss.jar')
}

 createJar.dependsOn(deleteJar, build)
```

I will try that  code but jar file not created in the specfic location only empty folder .

Its not work for me.......... Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a .jar out from an Android Studio project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712714/how-to-make-a-jar-out-from-an-android-studio-project)

Comment: thanks.i will refer that link only.but it not working for me.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/35431416/4845438

Comment: thanks.yes that's correct. but when i put that code it does'nt create a jar file.simply empty folder in that location.please help me to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

First,Build, Select build variants  and you can change the app's build variant. to release. Second, you might use like this code to gradl
look the path "from" carefully.
and set the path include 'classes.jar'
Wish it could be help..