# Android-How to convert module to jar

Tags: java, android

I have imported library module in my project. but I want to convert existing library module to a jar and then I want to use this jar(library module) in my current project.but I did this all process and trying to a specific class in my layout but The following classes could not be found:
- com.halilibo.bettervideoplayer.BetterVideoPlayer, this error getting.
The main issue is that jar file only contain java classes but module also contains resources, drawable also. I converted my module to jar but specific class is not getting imported.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a .jar out from an Android Studio project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712714/how-to-make-a-jar-out-from-an-android-studio-project)

Comment: one issue is that jar file only contain java classes and in my module it has resources also

Comment: Resources should go under `src/main/resources/`, not under `src/main/java`. If you have done that it should work automatically.

Comment: Yes it's same but not fetching that class information

Answer (score 1):

You need to create `AAR` file instead of `JAR` as you have to include resources.

> Library reuse has long been available in Java based applications
>   through Java Archive (.jar) files.  Android AAR files build upon this
>   concept to allow you to package not only the source code but also the
>   libraries self contained Android resources. The library can have its
>   own manifest and resources and can also optionally provide assets, NDK
>   built libraries, proguard configuration and even its own custom lint
>   filters.  This is all bundled into a zip archive that can be published
>   to a repository for your team (or the world!) to get easy access from
>   a Gradle build.

1. Start by selecting New Module… from the File menu
2. Select Android Library as the module to be created
3. Step through the process of using a template for the creation of your library much like creating a new project

One key difference in the created library and an Android application will be the libraries Gradle build script includes apply plugin: `com.android.library` instead of apply plugin: `com.android.application`.

When you build your project the AAR file will automatically be assembled and placed in these folders

```
| build
| outputs
      | aar
           | applib-debug.aar
           | applib-release.aar
```

https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/02/23/building-an-aar-library-in-android-studio/