# jar not created even after including lint operations

Tags: android, android-studio, jar

I am trying to convert my Android app to JAR.

While clicking the build option in the GRADLE toolbar, it shows this error:

> `Fix the issues identified by lint or add the following to your build script to proceed with errors:
>   ...
>   android {
>       lintOptions {
>           abortOnError false
>       }
>   }`

Now I added these lines to my `build.gradle` but JAR has not been created and not showing any errors too. Pls help

Answer (score 0):

try using the `creteFullJarDebug` or `createFullJarRelease` that are located in the *other* on the same tab

Comment: Thanks Nikos Hidalgo, but i am not having such an option under the others tab.

Comment: @PeerMohamed are you using an older version of Android Studio? Maybe it's worth checking this answer as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35431416/10300673

Comment: I will try this and come back to you @Nikos Hidalgo

Comment: I checked the site, the code says to delete the previous jar that is present and create one. But my problem is not able to create one. but thanks for the guide @Nikos Hidalgo

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there is a bug with fetching lintOptions. Maybe your problem is related to that. Try to change the order of repositories, move `google()` to the top in your project gradle and app gradle(if it exists) as well.

[image]