# Error inflating class ja.burhanrashid52.photoeditor.PhotoEditorView

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Currently, I am developing an android app using [PhotoEditor](https://github.com/burhanrashid52/PhotoEditor) library.
I have followed the `Getting Started` and `Setting up the View` sections as explained on the page.
However, somehow, I cannot inflate the UI XML that contains `PhotoEditorView`.
Here is my code:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <ja.burhanrashid52.photoeditor.PhotoEditorView
            android:id="@+id/photoEditorView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </ja.burhanrashid52.photoeditor.PhotoEditorView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    try {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.app_fragment_edit_picture, container, false);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        LogHelper.LogError("TEST");
    }

    return null;
}
```

I put the `try-catch` and `return null` there only for testing.

Error:

> Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating
>   class ja.burhanrashid52.photoeditor.PhotoEditorView

Does anyone have a clue?

As requested, here is the full stack trace:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML
>   file line #9: Error inflating class
>   ja.burhanrashid52.photoeditor.PhotoEditorView     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)  at
>   com.mobileop.app.gui.fragments.EditPictureFragment.onCreateView(EditPictureFragment.java:54)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3273)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3229)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2466)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1483)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
>     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
>   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9:
>   Error inflating class ja.burhanrashid52.photoeditor.PhotoEditorView
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)     ...
>   30 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)   ...
>   35 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution
>   of: Lja/burhanrashid52/photoeditor/R$styleable;   at
>   ja.burhanrashid52.photoeditor.PhotoEditorView.init(PhotoEditorView.java:72)
>     at
>   ja.burhanrashid52.photoeditor.PhotoEditorView.(PhotoEditorView.java:48)
>     ... 37 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find
>   class "ja.burhanrashid52.photoeditor.R$styleable" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.mobileop-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mobileop-1/lib/arm,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]    at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)     ... 39 more
>     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   ja.burhanrashid52.photoeditor.R$styleable         at
>   java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)       at
>   java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)         at
>   java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)         at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)         ... 40 more
>     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the
>   boot class loader; no stack trace available

Comment: have you put that on your app-level build.gradle file:
implementation 'ja.burhanrashid52:photoeditor:0.4.0'

clean/build and retry

Comment: What is your full stack trace for this error?

Comment: @SebastienRieu I have put it like this: `implementation files('libs/photoeditor-0.4.0.jar')`. I name the library `photoeditor-0.4.0.jar`.
Previously, I have tried `implementation 'ja.burhanrashid52:photoeditor:0.4.0'`, but it result an error `Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs`

Comment: have you retry to add the dependency normally ?
if it doesn't work could you put you all manifest error stacktrace ?

Comment: @MarcoBatista I have added the full stack trace on the question as requested. (y)

Comment: Yep, it seems to be an issue with the dependency as others are pointing out. It seems that it isn't able to find the `PhotoEditorView` class.

Comment: I have followed the steps to generate the `.jar` file here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52681317/3097810 and there are `classes.jar`, `full.jar`, and `res.jar`. As suggested in the article, I only took the `full.jar`. Should I take all `.jar` files instead then?

Comment: I also followed the steps here https://stackoverflow.com/a/35241990/3097810 to add the `.jar` file.

Comment: Also, when I press Ctrl + B on <ja.burhanrashid52.photoeditor.PhotoEditorView, it points me to the library class. So, I think the dependency should be correct, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Whole Code with Main,fragment xmls and classes.

**MainActivity XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity Java**

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class PhotoEditorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
FragmentManager fragManager;
FragmentTransaction fragTransaction;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo_editor);

    fragManager=getFragmentManager();
    fragManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
    fragTransaction=fragManager.beginTransaction();
    fragTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new PhotoEditorFragment());
    fragTransaction.commit();

}
}
```

**Fragment XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent">

<ja.burhanrashid52.photoeditor.PhotoEditorView
    android:id="@+id/photoEditorView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ja.burhanrashid52.photoeditor.PhotoEditorView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Fragment Java**

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class PhotoEditorFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle 
savedInstanceState) {
    View itemView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.photo_editor_fragment,container,false);
    try
    {
        return itemView;}
    catch (Exception e){
        return null;
    }

}
}
```

This code runs fine on my android studio. 
I have not imported the jar but added the dependency in gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'ja.burhanrashid52:photoeditor:0.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running it on a device? In my case, android studio doesn’t show any error. Only when I run it on a device, then it shows the mentioned error.

Comment: @YusrilMaulidanRaji Yes I have and it didn't show me an error. Run the above code, I am sure it will do.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. Okay then. I'll retry by making a small project. Hopefully, I can point out the real source of the problem

Comment: It works now, thanks! The keyword is `I have not imported the jar but added the dependency in gradle`. Previously, I did that as well, but there was an error in `AndroidManifest.xml`. I thought I had to import the jar first, but I shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

You have to return a View, you are returning null in the function.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle 
savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
try {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.app_fragment_edit_picture, container, 
false);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    LogHelper.LogError("TEST");
}

return view;
}
```

Comment: No, I put it there only for debugging. As I mentioned in the question: `I put the try-catch and return null there only for testing.`. It always goes to `catch`.

Comment: @YusrilMaulidanRaji Well then you should return view in try block and null in the catch block. Returning the view is necessary as the function's return type is view.  public "View" onCreateView(....)

Comment: Yes, I did it like so. But still, it triggers the exception. Therefore, I don't think that's the source of the problem

Comment: @YusrilMaulidanRaji Is your layout file error free. How did you import this library "ja.burhanrashid52.photoeditor.PhotoEditorView". Did you add any dependency in the gradle file.

Comment: Yes, I can compile and run it on my phone. I have also set it in gradle: `implementation files('libs/ja.burhanrashid52-photoeditor-0.4.0.jar')`.

Comment: I have followed the steps to generate the .jar file here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52681317/3097810 . I also followed the steps here https://stackoverflow.com/a/35241990/3097810 to add the .jar file.

Comment: Also, when I press Ctrl + B on `<ja.burhanrashid52.photoeditor.PhotoEditorView`, it points me to the library class. So, I think the dependency should be correct, shouldn't it?

Comment: @YusrilMaulidanRaji Yes, it means the dependency is imported. I have tested your code with fragments and added an updated answer. It works fine.